# Passing input text value to another input text with jQuery

Tags: jquery

It's a very basic question which bugging me and nothing seems working. The page contain 2 forms (source-target) and I want to pass the value of one input(`#query2`) to another (`#query`) on blur event.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#query2").blur(function(e){
        //test 1
        $('form[name=searchheadForm] #query').val($(this).val());
        //test 2
        $("form#search_head#query").val($(this).val());
    });
    });
```

Any idea? TIA.

Comment: This selector doesn't make sense : "form#search_head#query"

Comment: Can you show some HTML.

Comment: you cannot have 2 elements with same Id

Comment: I;ve giving the answer twice, but appearantly people care more about not reposting (an updated, better answer) than the actual answer, here is my jsFiddle which the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/VbVdM/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of your selectors are wrong, here are the better solutions:

```
// Your method 1, I've added quotes. Not 100% needed, but it's good practice
// Also, I've encountered cases where no quotes gave an error:
$('form[name="searchheadForm"] #query').val($(this).val());

// Your method 2 
$("form#search_head #query").val( $(this).val() ); // space for #query

// or the last one better (this method is the one I recommand, id is always faster)
$("#query").val( $(this).val() ); // There is always 1 ID, so a ID selector only needs 1 refference
```

If you did this, it will work:

http://jsfiddle.net/VbVdM/2/ <- working example

Comment: 1) Your fiddle proves the quotes aren't needed. 2) I explained my downvote 3) don't repost your answer to try to dodge downvotes

Comment: The 2nd and 3rd option works on a fly. thanks. But for some reason option did not work. Both form name and input id are correct.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this example :**

**jquery**

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#query1').change(function(){
            var val = $('#query1').val();
            $('#query2').val(val);
        });
     });
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="query1"/>
<input type="text" id="query2"/>
```

Comment: Explain down vote ? i m just set example for how to pass first textbox value to another.

Comment: @Martijn ohh sorry it was my mistake i was forgot to define type.

Comment: Don't worry about it. @Martijn is just mad and downvoting everyone.

Comment: Yeah, thats exactly why I removed my downvote after Devang updated his answers after my comment hy I downvoted, because i'm mad.

Comment: @Martijn its ok martijn.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#query2").blur(function(){
       $('#query').val($(this).val());
   });
});
```

That should take the value from #query2 and put it into #query on blur. You also use keypress to do it in realtime.

Comment: This code work on a fly but also I need to reference through form name or id, whatever is working. Thanks anyway, found the solution.